# pyplot - how to show image on top

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following code that presents the result of a gaussian pyramid -

```
fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.figimage(gp[0], cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.figimage(gp[1], 512, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.figimage(gp[2], 512 + 256, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.figimage(gp[3], 512 + 256 + 128, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.figimage(gp[4], 512 + 256 + 128 + 64, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.figimage(gp[5], 512 + 256 + + 128 + 64 + 32, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

plt.show()
```

`gp` is a list of images of type `np.array` refers to arrays of dimensions 512X512, 256X256 and so on.
This codes generates the following image:
[image]

(the original image is from `skimage.data.camera()`)

My question is: how do I make the pictures to be shown on the top side of the image and not on the bottom?

Comment: Are you open to using a different approach?

Comment: of course, anything that works ia fine

Comment: In that case, enjoy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is suggested by the documentation of [`plt.figimage`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figimage) itself:

> figimage complements the axes image ([imshow()](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow)) which will be resampled to fit the current axes. If you want a resampled image to fill the entire figure, you can define an [Axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) with size [0,1,0,1].

Links are actually present in the online documentation. Also, I just submitted a [PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/7659) to fix `[0, 1, 0, 1]` to `[0, 0, 1, 1]`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
# Create axis stretched across the entire figure. anchor='N' will
# keep it anchored to the top and left when it gets resized to fit
# the image bounds (default is the center).
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1], anchor='NW', frameon=False)
# Remove the spines and ticks of the axis (frameon=False in the
# line above made it transparent)
ax.set_axis_off()

offset = -0.5
for im in gp:
    height, width = im.shape
    # Plot the images upside-down with origin=lower
    ax.imshow(im, extent=[offset, offset + width, -0.5, height], origin='lower', cmap='gray')
    offset += width

ax.set_xlim([-0.5, offset])
# Flip the y-axis
ax.set_ylim([gp[0].shape[0] - 0.5, -0.5])

plt.show()
```

One key difference with `figure.figimage` is that the images will scale as you change the size of the figure rather than mapping to the screen pixel-by-pixel.

I tested using the following definition of `gp`:

```
from skimage.data import camera

g = camera()
gp = [g[::2**x, ::2**x] for x in range(6)]
```

Here is the result:

[image]

And here is an example with `anchor` not set explicitly in `fig.add_axes`:

[image]

**UPDATE**

[PR #7659](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/7659) was accepted, so the corrected documentation for matplotlib will read:

> figimage complements the axes image ([imshow()](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow)) which will be resampled to fit the current axes. If you want a resampled image to fill the entire figure, you can define an [Axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) with **extents [0,0,1,1]**.